# How and why does the compiler replace extern functions with a null function?

Tags: c, linux, macros, usb, extern

Consider the following code in linux/drivers/usb/hid-core.c:

```
static void hid_process_event (struct hid_device *hid,
                               struct hid_field *field,
                               struct hid_usage *usage,
                               __s32 value)
{
   hid_dump_input(usage, value);
   if (hid->claimed & HID_CLAIMED_INPUT)
         hidinput_hid_event(hid, field, usage, value);
#ifdef CONFIG_USB_HIDDEV
   if (hid->claimed & HID_CLAIMED_HIDDEV)
         hiddev_hid_event(hid, usage->hid, value);
#endif
}
```

Here the author does not want to call hiddev_hid_event() if a specific configuration option is not enabled. This is because that function will not even be present if the configuration option is not enabled.

To remove this #ifdef, the following change was made to include/linux/hiddev.h:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_USB_HIDDEV
   extern void hiddev_hid_event (struct hid_device *,
                                 unsigned int usage,
                                 int value);
#else
   static inline void
   hiddev_hid_event (struct hid_device
*hid,
                     unsigned int usage,
                     int value) { }
#endif
```

Then drivers/usb/hid-core.c was changed to:

```
static void hid_process_event
                           (struct hid_device *hid,
                            struct hid_field *field,
                            struct hid_usage *usage,
                            __s32 value)
{
   hid_dump_input(usage, value);
   if (hid->claimed & HID_CLAIMED_INPUT)
         hidinput_hid_event(hid, field, usage, value);
   if (hid->claimed & HID_CLAIMED_HIDDEV)
         hiddev_hid_event(hid, usage->hid, value);
}
```

If CONFIG_USB_HIDDEV is not enabled, the compiler will replace the call to hiddev_hid_event() with a null function call and then optimize away the if statement entirely.

What I can't understand is how the call to hiddev_hid_event() is replaced with a null function by the compiler. The only difference I see is that return type `extern void` has been replaced with `static inline void`. Does this means that all extern functions if not defined will automatically become null function?

Ref: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5780?page=0,3

Comment: I would be careful with such an obfuscation. The original version is at least clear that something is not called if a CONFIG variable is not set. By hiding the implementation a programmer may spend some time scratching their heads as to why the function in their editor never appears to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function actually *is* defined, but has an empty body:

```
static inline void
hiddev_hid_event (struct hid_device *hid,
                 unsigned int usage,
                 int value) 
{ }
```

Optimizing away inline functions with empty bodies is trivial, I guess.

Comment: Yeah right, I overlooked the empty function body. This means there is no automatic conversion to null, we have to manually provide a null function body.